# Picking two strings from a file

Tags: powershell

I want to extract either of two string by reading each line of a file in PowerShell.

Example:

`desc.txt` contains:

```
Description : Attaching new instance: inst-id
Description : Detaching new instance: inst-id
Description : Launching new instance: inst-id
```

I want to read desc.txt line by line, pick the inst-id if the line has either "Attaching" or "Launching".

I am able to extract just one string among the two by this code:

```
$b=Get-Content .\desc.txt
$b | Select-String -SimpleMatch "Launching"
```

Output:

```
Description : Launching a instance: inst-id
```

Comment: You're on the right track. Get-Content and Select-String are exactly where I'd go for what you're looking to do. All you need now is the filter or regex that gives you the final result.

Comment: Thanks Booga..if you could please help on the code, i am struggling on this

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match more than one string, you need to use a regular expression. According to the [description of Select-String](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx), the parameter -SimpleMatch does not support Regular Expressions. Thus you need to use the -Pattern parameter.

Here's a full example to match both "Launching" and "Attaching":

```
$FileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()

@"
Description : Attaching new instance: inst-id
Description : Detaching new instance: inst-id
Description : Launching new instance: inst-id
"@ | Out-File -FilePath $FileName 

Get-Content -Path $FileName | Select-String -Pattern "Attaching|Launching"

Remove-Item -Path $FileName
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you want to extract the `inst-id` part from the lines I'd do something like this:

```psh
Get-Content .\desc.txt |
  ? { $_ -match '(?:Attaching|Launching).*:\s+(.*)$' } |
  % { $matches[1] }
```